# passing data from parent Tab layout activity to fragment stops swapping of tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have home activity which has 7 tabs. and for each tab I have created one fragment. Now I am transferring data from home fragment to other activity named Feature_Product_Activity which has 3 tabs, and here also for each tab I have created fragment. Then I am  passing data from `Feature_Product_Activity` to one of the child fragment named `FragmentFeatureOverview`.

This is the method for passing data from Container Activity named Feature_Product_Activity to child Fragment named FragmentFeatureOverview

```
public void getValueFromFragment()
    {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        getFeatureDescription= bundle.getString("desc");

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        b.putString("bb",getFeatureDescription);

        FragmentFeatureOverview ff = new FragmentFeatureOverview();
        ff.setArguments(b );
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,ff).commit();
 }
```

and in my fragment activity named FragmentFeatureOverview and getting data .

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feature_overview, container, false);

TextView description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.overview_Feature_description);

    if(getArguments()!=null) {
        String value = getArguments().getString("bb");
        System.out.println("bundle is not null"+value);
        description.setText(value);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I am getting the value in the bundle. But after setting the value in the TextView, Tabs Stops scrolling.

Any help will be greatly appreciated